# Facebook Javascript SDK /me multiple field calls with large photo type

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add parameters to my api call to facebook's javascript sdk. So far all of the calls are working, but I am having issues with adding a parameter to the picture, I want to return a large picture or be able to specify the height and width.

```
    FB.api('/me', {
                        fields: [
                          'last_name',
                          'first_name',
                          'email',
                          'location',
                          'picture'
                        ],
                        parameters: {
                          type: 'large'
                        }
                    )
```

I would like to keep the syntax of the call because it is very readable, I want to add the type large to the picture field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it like this?

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name,first_name,email,location,picture.type(large)'}, (response) => () {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I never saw the fields parameter as array in any docs, you should use a string instead.

Comment: Thanks! Not really sure why a string is the most optimal choice here but it works.